# Differentiation of Angular Velocities

Tags: calculus

It is safe to say that I am little rusty when it comes to maths, and this is particularly unhelpful when I am pursuing a career in electronics.
Anyway, I am required to differentiate the following three things with respect to time and I really am that bad at it that I have to ask.

**$$w_x=\dot\phi-n\theta$$**
**$$w_y=\dot\theta+n\phi$$**
**$$w_z=\dot\psi+n$$**
So I am wanting to get the derivative of these three equations, sorry if this is a terrible question.

It may or may not be worth noting that the angles are Euler angles if that means anything but probably better to just see them as symbols.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! So it looks like $\phi, \theta, \psi$ are all functions of $t$ -- is that correct?

Comment: Hi @EliRose, yes that would be correct

Comment: What is $n$? Where this formulas come from, it not resembles the usual relation between angular velocity and derivatives of Euler angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I am understanding you right, but would it not be:
$$\dot\omega_x = \ddot\phi - n\dot\theta$$ $$\dot\omega_y = \ddot\theta + n\dot\phi$$ $$\dot\omega_z = \ddot\psi$$
Where I am assuming that $\ n\ $ is constant. If $\ n\ $ also depends on $t$, then it would be
$$\dot\omega_x = \ddot\phi - n\dot\theta-\dot n\theta$$ $$\dot\omega_y = \ddot\theta + n\dot\phi + \dot n\phi$$ $$\dot\omega_z = \ddot\psi + \dot n$$

Comment: This is what I got when I tried and thought it couldn't be that simple... But it is. Yes n is constant as well, sorry, forgot to mention